# Teiid 15 - Query planner seems to incorrectly optimize the query with inner joins

Tags: teiid

We have a custom translator written that extends the SQLServerExecutionFactory, since Teiid 9.1. We have overridden the following translator capabilities to avoid push down of these cases.

> supportsUnions=false;    supportsExcept=false;
> supportsIntersect=false;    supportsInLineViews = false;
> supportsCaseExpressions = false;    supportGroupBy= false;

The following query

```
 SELECT emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name from emp
    INNER JOIN dept   ON dept.dept_id=emp.dept_id
    INNER JOIN company   ON comp.company_id=dept.company_id
```

gets transformed and reaches the translator as

```
select  emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name from emp where emp.dept_id is not null and dept.company_id is not null ORDER BY @@version OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

As you can see there is no join on the transformed query and the dept table seems to be missing, even though the tables column is used in the query.

Is this a defect or are we missing any translator capability that has been introduced since Teiid 13?.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a defect or are we missing any translator capability that has been introduced since Teiid 13?

What version are you seeing this on?  If it's 13+, please log an issue at https://issues.redhat.com/projects/TEIID

Without knowing the version and having a query debug plan, it's hard to say exactly what the nature of the issue is from just this.